# What's the difference between (-1).toShort and -1.toShort in Scala

Tags: scala, short

Given the following scala code:

```
val mapAll= Map("A"-> 1.toShort, "B"-> 2.toShort)
val map1 = Map("A"-> 1.toShort)
val map2 = mapAll.map(x => (x._2, map1.getOrElse(x._1, -1.toShort)))
```

In this case，the type of map2 shown in IDEA is Map[Short, Int].
What I need is Map[Short, Short]

However, if put the -1 into "()"  like this"

```
val map2 = mapAll.map(x => (x._2, map1.getOrElse(x._1, (-1).toShort)))
```

It's just fine. the type of map2 shown in IDEA is Map[Short, Short]

So， What's the difference between  "(-1).toShort" and "-1.toShort"

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Me either :}}

Answer (score 6):

There's no difference. You're probably tricked by IntelliJ's bad type inference in this case. You can see this when compiling scalac with the `-Xprint:typer` flag:

```
val map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Short,Short] = 
  mapAll.map[(Short, Short), scala.collection.immutable.Map[Short,Short]](
    ((x: (String, Short)) => scala.Tuple2.apply[Short, Short](
       x._2, map1.getOrElse[Short](x._1, -1.toShort))))
      (immutable.this.Map.canBuildFrom[Short, Short]);
```

We can also verify this by simplifying the example:

```
val shortOne = -1.toShort
val shortTwo = (-1).toShort
```

And compiling with `-Xprint:jvm` to see the final emitted step:

```
val shortOne: Short = -1.toShort();
val shortTwo: Short = -1.toShort();
```

You can see both are identical.

Answer (score 2):

On Short, - is defined like this :  `def unary_- : Int`

Happens, `-1.toShort` is understood as `-(1.toShort)` by IDEA, of type `Int`, and `(-1).toShort` is correctly typed `Short`, since this is the type of `toShort` which is now "called" after the - instead of before.